# What is ctx and arg in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

So I have been learning discord.py and keep getting stuck in the same part. I don't know what ctx and arg mean. I can't find much in their documentation. I've seen it like ctx.send or async def blank(ctx). What does it do and what use cases would it be used for?

Answer (score 3):

[`ctx`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#context) is short for `context`. It is used by `discord.ext.commands` and includes information like who executed the command, where it was executed and so on. `ctx.send()` is basically a helper function which makes your life easier. You can read its [description in the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send) to find out how it works and what it does. You just need to read it.

---

`arg` is short for `argument`. It is usually used as a [variable length argument list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/).